# Creating an object of one class in another, what is the relationship in a UML class diagram?

Tags: java, android, uml

I have a SessionManager class, that I create objects of in every class a user needs to be logged in to reach I am unsure of the type of relationship created here as I seem to have confused myself with all of the definitions online. I am trying to create a UML class diagram representing all of the classes in my application. Would this be an Aggregation relationship or simply an associated relationship?

I have no classes that extend each other as I have made an Android app that uses intents to pass from activity to activity, I'm simply creating objects of some classes in other classes.

Additionally, is there any way to represent an intent on a UML class diagram?

Creating SessionManager Object:

```
SessionManager sessionManager;
```

Using checkLogin() method from SessionManagerClass in onCreate method:

```
sessionManager = new SessionManager(this);
        sessionManager.checkLogin();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would have `HAS-A` relationship, in other words, Aggregation.

> Aggregation is a special form of association. It is a relationship between two classes like association, however its a directional association, which means it is strictly a one-way association. It represents a **HAS-A** relationship

### UML Construction Demo

[image: Aggregation UML sample]

[image: Aggregation UML]

[Source](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/)

More info:

[Aggregation vs composition](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/61527)

Comment: Fixed, I should have cropped out irrelevant diagrams.

Comment: Fixed the source

Comment: Sorry to keep you busy. But what you call "aggregation" is a shared composition. Please read on p. 110 of UML 2.5 that this relation has no defined semantics. The linked answer is definitely outdated (it was valid in older UML versions, tough)

Comment: The aggregation definition is wrong.
It is not a "HAS-A" but a "WILL NOT EXIST WITHOUT A"

ie: an InvoiceLine will not exist without an Invoice containing it.

Comment: @LuisAlvaradoDay A fridge can be aggregated into a Kitchen. A fridge can exist without a Kitchen. We don't want to destroy the fridge with the kitchen. Please share the link to the source describing why aggregation does not have "HAS-A" relation

Comment: @TaseerAhmad Sorry for not being clear I'm talking about "composite aggregation"  which is a subtype of aggregation. So disregard.

Answer (score 0):

I think Composition relationship is correct in this case.

```
class A {
   private B b = new B();
}
//or
class A {
   private B b;
   public A() {
      b = new B();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Composite aggregation is about runtime. Composed elements are to destroyed along with the composing element. The table on p. 110 of UML 2.5 states

> **composite** | Indicates that the Property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed objects (see the definition of parts in 11.2.3).

It seems appropriate to model this (filled diamond at the association end) in your case. The `SessionManager` should be some kind of factory producing `Session` objects which it holds responsibility for.